# Expectation value of $p^2$ coming out complex

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, mathematics

I've got the wave function

$$\Psi(x,t) = \frac{e^{-x^2/4(a^2+i\hbar t/2m)}}{\sqrt[4]{2\pi}\sqrt{a+i\hbar t/2ma}}$$

and am trying to find the expectation value of $p^2$.  So I simplify things a bit by setting

$$\Psi(x,t) = \frac{e^{-x^2/4(a^2+i\hbar t/2m)}}{\sqrt[4]{2\pi}\sqrt{a+i\hbar t/2ma}} = \frac{e^{-x^2/A}}{B},$$

and then evaluating the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx\ \Psi^*(-\hbar^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2})\Psi$, and simplifying I'm getting

$$\frac{2\hbar^2}{|A|^2|B|^2}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}|A|\operatorname{Im}(A)\color{red}{iA^*}}{[\operatorname{Re}(A)]^{3/2}}$$

Before even plugging in my expressions for $A$ and $B$ I see something wrong: this is the expectation value of an observable and thus should be real.  But all of the numbers in this last expression are real *except* the part in red which will be complex.  Thus I've made some mistake.

I can't see a mistake in my calculations.  Can anyone see where I am going wrong here?

---

**Edit:**  Here is what I did to get that answer:

$$\begin{gather}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{e^{-x^2/A}}{B} = \frac{-2x}{A}\frac{e^{-x^2/A}}{B} \\ \implies \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\frac{e^{-x^2/A}}{B} = \left[\frac{-2}{A}+\frac{4x^2}{A^2}\right]\frac{e^{-x^2/A}}{B} = \frac{-2}{A}\left[1-\frac{2x^2}{A}\right]\frac{e^{-x^2/A}}{B} \\ \implies \hat p\frac{e^{-x^2/A}}{B} = \frac{2\hbar^2}{A}\left[1-\frac{2x^2}{A}\right]\frac{e^{-x^2/A}}{B} \\ \implies \frac{e^{-x^2/A^*}}{B^*}\hat p\frac{e^{-x^2/A}}{B} = \frac{e^{-x^2/A^*}}{B^*}\frac{2\hbar^2}{A}\left[1-\frac{2x^2}{A}\right]\frac{e^{-x^2/A}}{B} = \frac{2\hbar^2}{A|B|^2}\left[1-\frac{2x^2}{A}\right]e^{-x^2(\frac 1A+\frac 1{A^*})}\end{gather}$$

Then I use Mathematica to compute $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\ \left[1-\frac{2x^2}{A}\right]e^{-x^2\operatorname{Re}(A)/|A|^2} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}|A|(A-\operatorname{Re}(A))}{\operatorname{Re}(A)^{3/2}}$$

From there I multiply the "constant" back in and rearrange:

$$\frac{2\hbar^2}{A|B|^2}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}|A|(A-\operatorname{Re}(A))}{\operatorname{Re}(A)^{3/2}} = \frac{2\hbar^2}{A|B|^2}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}|A|(i\operatorname{Im}(A))}{\operatorname{Re}(A)^{3/2}}\frac{A^*}{A^*} = \frac{2\hbar^2}{|A|^2|B|^2}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}|A|\operatorname{Im}(A)iA^*}{\operatorname{Re}(A)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: You've calculated the integral incorrectly. Write your computation in more detail

Comment: Just in case, I've computed it myself and know that the result is different and real.

Comment: @OON Done.$\ \ $

Comment: BTW, I also worked out the integral that I did with Mathematica by integral table just to make sure.  And I got the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$z=\operatorname{Re}(z)+i\operatorname{Im}(z),\quad z^\ast=\operatorname{Re}(z)-i\operatorname{Im}(z)$$
therefore
$$z+z^\ast=2\operatorname{Re}(z)$$
You lost factor of $2$ in
$$\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{A^\ast}=2\frac{\operatorname{Re}(A)}{|A|^2}$$

Comment: Wow.  I can't believe that little mistake had such a drastic effect on the integral.  Thanks for spotting my error!